# TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, plugins, axios, nuxt.js

I fetch an api in my `api/repository.js` from a component through my vuex actions:

```
//component:
<button @click="click">button</button>

methods:{
  ...mapActions(['click'])
}

//store:
async click({commit}) {
  await this.$repository.liveEvents.genreById().then(data => {
    // commit
  }
}

// api/liveEvents.js:
const baseUrl = process.env.config.baseUrl;

export default ($axios) => ({
   genreById($axios) {
    return $axios.get(`${baseUrl}`)
  }
})

// api/repository.js
import LiveEvents from '~/api/liveEventsApi'

export const repository = ($axios) => ({
  liveEvents: LiveEvents($axios)
})
```

I have also created a plugin for it:

```
// plugins/repository.js:
import { repository } from '~/api/Repository.js'

export default (context, inject) => {
  inject('repository', repository(context.$axios))
}
```

And have added it to my `nuxt.config.js`:

```
  plugins: [
    { src: '~plugins/repository.js'}
  ],
```

However when I click on the button in my component, I get the error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`!
I think the issue is `api/repository.js` somehow doesn't understand `$axios`. However when I use `$axios` in my store or directly in my components I don't get any errors! Anyone knows what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

`context` object doesn't contain **$axios** instance directly. $axios instance lies inside `app` object. You have to access to $axios like below:

```
import { repository } from '~/api/Repository.js'
 
export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  inject('repository', repository(app.$axios))
}
```

**<----------------------- Update after response ------------------------->**

In your api/liveEvents.js page you declared function wrong.
Here you have to remove `$axios` argument from `genreById` function because it might be undefined if you don't pass axios to your function.

```
export default ($axios) => ({
   genreById($axios) {
             ^^^^^^ - remove it
    return $axios.get(`${baseUrl}`)
  }
})
```

If you call `$axios.$get(...)` in the context which `$axios` is undefined, JS throws error like this `TypeError: Cannot read property '$get' of undefined`.

Try to review your code and check if you have a syntax error like above.